# Including .prj file for new CRS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a coordinate system in coal grid which is exclusively for coalfields of India in QGIS.

I want to transfer it from the coal grid to UTM.

I have .prj file of coal grid, But I don't know how to include it. How to set custom project system?

Comment: What file format is the grid?

Comment: You can run `gdalsrsinfo yourfile.prj` to get the proj.4 string for use in QGIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is .prj file not being retrieved by QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269807/why-is-prj-file-not-being-retrieved-by-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

If the .prj file has the same name as your file and it is in the same directory, QGIS should already detect the file and configure the project's CRS to it.

If not, right click to the layer, Save as..., and select the CRS that you want.

EDIT:
In case you want to create the .prj file by yourself, add the CRS in WKT format. Example of the EPSG 3035 CRS in WKT:

```
PROJCS["ETRS89_LAEA_Europe",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",52],PARAMETER["central_meridian",10],PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Comment: please tell me how can I set new CRS by using .prj file in QGIS.

Comment: The .prj file is created automatically when you do the previously mentioned step, but, if you insist on doing it directly with the file, you just need to create a text file `samename.prj` and write in it the Well Known Text (WKT) format of the projection. See the EDIT in my answer

Comment: I suggest you emphasize (more) on your answer OP needs to reproject the data, rather than just change/create the content of the .prj file.